# Navigation controller SIGABRT iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sigabrt

My application is Crashing on this line
Program receiving signal:`SIGABRT` on

```
[navigationController initWithRootViewController:homeview];
```

Is there any suggestions specific to iOS 5???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code that contains what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

You code looks a bit weird, I'l make the an assumption (I know it this the mother) thet navigationController is your ivar voor `UINavigationController`.

The you should load it like this:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeview];
```